# How to specify an ETag in the .Net client library of the YouTube API v3

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api, etag

The YouTube API v3 documentation recommends using ETags for better performance:

> Your application can cache API resources and their ETags. Then, when your application requests a stored resource again, it specifies the ETag associated with that resource. If the resource has changed, the API returns the modified resource and the ETag associated with that version of the resource. If the resource has not changed, the API returns an HTTP 304 response (Not Modified)

From [Getting Started with the YouTube Data API\Optimizing performance\Using ETags](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags)

My question is how can you specify the associated ETag using the .Net client library to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea with using etags is that the request adds an "If-None-Match" header in the request that's set to the value of the etag; the server is already configured to respond to that header by checking the etag and returning the 304 if nothing has changed. So really it comes down to whether or not a given client library supports the adding of a custom header like "If-None-Match," and then has code to handle the 304 if it comes back (or if not to replace its cache).

I know the YouTube javascript library does (when constructing the `gapi.client.request` object, you just pass a 'headers' object that has the additonal headers), but from my superficial reading of the .Net client code (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Requests/RequestBuilder.cs), it appears that the .Net client doesn't let you set this header currently. You could always make the direct GET requests outside of the client structure, or extend the client to include the functionality, as long as you subsequently handled the caching part as well. I may be incorrect, though, and looking in the wrong code.

Comment: The .Net client lets you set an `ETagAction` (`Ignore`/`IfMatch`/`IfNoneMatch`) and internally sets the ETag when the operation regards a single item (e.g. updating a channel).  It doesn't let you use ETags with the list operation.

Comment: I'm actually not even sure what's the meaning of an ETag for a search operation. When is it updated?

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't let you use etag with List operation but only with Insert and Update?  It feels natural to be able to use it with List so if the data hasn't changed it won't return it again.